# View is returning random results when no filter is selected in Drupal. Why?

Tags: view, default

In drupal I have created a view to display node's title and added exposed filter for filtering content. When the view page is loaded it is returning two nodes, I do not know on what basis it is returning those two nodes. I want no result to be displayed until I select some value in filter. Please suggest?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at the [Help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially [the Asking section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We'll need more information to help. We'll need to know what database engine you're using (PostgreSQL, MySQL for examples). I suspect we'll also need to see the table definition, some sample data, and expected output. Consider providing a http://sqlfiddle.com/ for database questions; they tend to be *very* helpful. ...Erm, when SQL Fiddle is working.

Answer (score 0):

Views is a query builder that starts with the simplest, broadest possible query, and filters are required to narrow that query to include *only* the items you wish. If you are familiar with SQL syntax, the default query would look something like this:

```
SELECT title, body FROM 'node'
```

This is why you're seeing two nodes when you load the page. There's no filter applied, so it's showing everything.

In order to get your View to *only* display items once the user has selected a value with the exposed filter, go into the Advanced > Exposed Form > Exposed Form Style and select *Input required*. I have tested this using Views 7.x-3.7 and I believe it will give you the behaviour you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @chiddicks. It worked :) But why only those two nodes, it should display all the nodes?

Comment: Are you certain there is neither an active filter or contextual filter on the view? Perhaps previewing the SQL query would help you debug, which can be done by going to Structure > Views > Settings > Show the SQL query.